# Firebase stops working whenever I add FlutterFire packages

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

Whenever I try to set up firebase for iOS, all works fine until I add the 'cloud_firestore:' package (or any other FlutterFire package) into the pubspec.yaml folder. I get similar error messages each time. The only package firebase-related package that does not bring up an error is the firebase_core package. My most common error output is pasted below:

```
*Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/Jon/crud/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Network/GULNetw
    orkURLSession.m:55:3: warning: 'NSURLSession' is only available on iOS
    7.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability]
      NSURLSession *__weak _Nullable _URLSession;
      ^
    In module 'Foundation' imported from
    /Users/Jon/crud/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Network/GULNetw
    orkURLSession.m:15:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.pla
    tform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/F
    oundation.framework/Headers/NSURLSession.h:123:12: note: 'NSURLSession'
    has been explicitly marked partial here
    @interface NSURLSession : NSObject
               ^
    In file included from
    /Users/Jon/crud/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Network/GULNetw
    orkURLSession.m:17:
    /Users/Jon/crud/ios/Pods/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities/Network/Private
    /GULNetworkURLSession.h:33:12: note: annotate 'GULNetworkURLSession'
    with an availability attribute to silence this warning
    @interface GULNetworkURLSession : NSObject
               ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/Jon/crud/ios/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/Firebase/Database/Persistence/
    FCachePolicy.m:17:9: fatal error: 'FCachePolicy.h' file not found
    #import "FCachePolicy.h"
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.*
```

I have attempted to make a new FCachePolicy.h folder using github references and copy that in but that just leads to an endless list of more Pods files being reported to me as not found. I am both very frustrated and lost for ideas at this point - any help or advice at this point would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you add the firestore package you need to add a GoogleService-Info.plist to the project, too

To do so you need to create a Firebase project, add your iOS bundle ID and download the additional plist file.

A full to tutorial on how to get that file and how to add that to your project you can get in the official firebase flutter codelab here (step 7):

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#6